# Rounding last decimal place to 0?

Tags: php, rounding

I tried `round`, `ceil` and `floor`, but they do not seem to do what I want (or I dont see the wood for the trees :-))

This is what I want:

```
1.44 --> 1.40
1.23 --> 1.20
3.50 --> 4.00
2.48 --> 2.50
...
```

I did not find a way to achieve that. Should be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `round()` and `number_format()`:

For example:

```
$number = 1.44;
number_format(round($number, 1), 2, '.', ''); // 1.40
```

Comment: It doesn't solve correctly the case of `3.50`, it should return `4.00`. But your code return `3.50`

Comment: @Martin because it is in the initial question

Comment: Yeah, its good this way

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `sptrintf` to format the number to 1 decimal, then append a `0` behind it:

```php
sprintf('%0.1f0', $test)
```

---

Test cases:

```php
<?php

foreach ([ 1.44, 1.23, 3.50, 2.48 ] as $test) {
    $rounded = sprintf('%0.1f0', $test);
    var_dump($rounded);
}
```

```
string(4) "1.40"
string(4) "1.20"
string(4) "3.50"
string(4) "2.50"
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLKy2/KDUxOUNBI1rBUM/ERAdIGhnrKBjrmRroKBjpmVgoxCokFiuolKQWl2gqVHNxqhTll@alpKYo2CoUFxRl5pWkaairGugZphmo60CVWXNxliUWxaeU5hZowJQDBWu5/v8HAA)

---

As string, since trailing `0` on a float are removed by PHP

Comment: It doesn't solve correctly the case of `3.50`, it should return `4.00`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native php function already doing what you want. We will need to do it ourself. First by finding the depth of the decimal part, then by rounding depending on depth.

```
<?php

function roundToSecondLastDigit(float $number): float{
    $decimal = $number - intval($number);
    $depth = strlen((string) $decimal) - 2;
    
    return round($number, $depth - 1);
}

echo roundToSecondLastDigit(1.44) . "\n"; //1.4
echo roundToSecondLastDigit(1.23) . "\n"; //1.2
echo roundToSecondLastDigit(3.50) . "\n"; //4
echo roundToSecondLastDigit(2.48) . "\n"; //2.5
```

You can print your number with the precision you want with `number_format` then.

```
echo number_format(roundToSecondLastDigit(2.48), 2, '.', ''); //2.50
```

Comment: The examples given by the OP retain the final zero, whereas your examples do not.

Comment: Depending of the OP data representation.  
If it is float represented then `4.00 === 4`. The problem seems to be focus on the way the OP round more than on the string representation of it.  
Will add a bit about it